# How to find the accuracy( quality ) of the generated question?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I have created a model that will generate a question from paragraph. generated questions are stored in list. from that generated questions some questions are good but some are meaning less. for example

```
Where did According to?
When did From?
etc.
```

I want to find the accuracy of the question or how meaningful the question is. and based on the accuracy user will select the questions.

I have tried with this the **language_tool_python library.**
I though this will make my question meaningful based on grammar. But it is not helpful. It is not helpful for quality of question, it will just correcting the grammatical errors.

for question generation I am using this link for my reference.
[question generation](https://github.com/Sanskar-Jain/Automatic-Question-Generator/blob/master/.ipynb_checkpoints/Code-checkpoint.ipynb)

so, how to find the accuracy of the generated questions?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to properly evaluate a task like this, it's to have human annotators judge the quality a sample of generated questions. It's common to annotate with a likert score from 1 to 5, often actually with two scores: one for fluency and one for meaningfulness.

By definition it's impossible to reliably evaluate an automatic system with an automatic method, unless it can be proved that the automatic method is itself reliable. In order to prove this, one would have the same problem: human-annotated data is required. So there's no way to avoid it for serious evaluation.